# How to solve chemical equilibrium equations $\bf{N}^T\bf{X}+\bf{C}=\bf{Y}$ and $\bf{N}\ln\bf{Y}=\ln\bf{K}$

Tags: systems-of-equations, chemistry

Here are chemical equilibrium equations:

$\begin{cases}
\mathbf{N}^\text{T}\mathbf{X}+\mathbf{C}=\mathbf{Y}\\
\mathbf{N}\ln\mathbf{Y}=\ln\mathbf{K}
\end{cases}$

Here $\mathbf{C}=\begin{pmatrix}c_1\\c_2\\\vdots\\c_n\end{pmatrix}$ are initial concentrations (mol/L) of *n* types of substances;

$\mathbf{N}=\begin{pmatrix}
\nu_{11}&\nu_{12}&\cdots&\nu_{1n}\\
\nu_{21}&\nu_{22}&\cdots&\nu_{2n}\\
\vdots&\vdots&\ddots&\vdots\\
\nu_{m1}&\nu_{m2}&\cdots&\nu_{mn}\\
\end{pmatrix}$ are coefficients of *m* chemical reactions (negative for reagents, positive for products, and zero if the substance is not related to the reaction);

$\mathbf{X}=\begin{pmatrix}x_1\\x_2\\\vdots\\x_m\end{pmatrix}$ are amounts of reactions (concentration changes for each reaction);

$\mathbf{Y}=\begin{pmatrix}y_1\\y_2\\\vdots\\y_n\end{pmatrix}$ are final (equilibrium state) concentrations;

$\mathbf{K}=\begin{pmatrix}k_1\\k_2\\\vdots\\k_m\end{pmatrix}$ are equilibrium constants for each reaction.

I need to solve **X** (*m* variables) and **Y** (*n* variables) by given **C**, **N** and **K**, either analytic or numeric solutions.

**For Example**

0.1 mol/L ammonia solution, we have 2 equilibriums:

*A*. H<sub>2</sub>O = H<sup>+</sup> + OH<sup>-</sup> (concentration of H<sub>2</sub>O is not considered)

*B*. NH<sub>3</sub> + H<sub>2</sub>O = NH<sub>4</sub><sup>+</sup> + OH<sup>-</sup> (concentration of H<sub>2</sub>O is not considered)

Equilibrium constants:

[H<sup>+</sup>][OH<sup>−</sup>] = 10<sup>-14</sup>

[NH<sub>4</sub><sup>+</sup>][OH<sup>−</sup>]/[NH<sub>3</sub>] = 1.77×10<sup>−5</sup>

So we have 2 reactions (*A* and *B*) and 4 substances (H<sup>+</sup>, OH<sup>−</sup>, NH<sub>3</sub> and NH<sub>4</sub><sup>+</sup>), and known values are:

$\mathbf{C}=\begin{pmatrix}c_\text{H+}\\c_\text{OH-}\\c_\text{NH3}\\c_\text{NH4+}\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}0\\0\\0.1\\0\end{pmatrix}$

$\mathbf{N}=\begin{pmatrix}\nu_\text{A,H+}&\nu_\text{A,OH-}&0&0\\0&\nu_\text{B,OH-}&\nu_\text{B,NH3}&\nu_\text{B,NH4}\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}1&1&0&0\\0&1&-1&1\end{pmatrix}$

$\mathbf{K}=\begin{pmatrix}k_A\\k_B\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}10^{-14}\\1.77\times10^{-5}\end{pmatrix}$

The solutions are:

$\mathbf{X}=\begin{pmatrix}x_A\\x_B\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}7.57\times10^{-12}\\1.32\times10^{-3}\end{pmatrix}$

$\mathbf{Y}=\begin{pmatrix}y_\text{H+}\\y_\text{OH-}\\y_\text{NH3}\\y_\text{NH4+}\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}7.57\times10^{-12}\\1.32\times10^{-3}\\0.0987\\1.32\times10^{-3}\end{pmatrix}$

Here I used the proximation of $y_\text{OH-}=y_\text{NH4+}$, so just solved a quadratic equation.

But how can I solve a more complicated system like:

- H<sub>2</sub>O = H<sup>+</sup> + OH<sup>-</sup>
- NH<sub>3</sub> + H<sub>2</sub>O = NH<sub>4</sub><sup>+</sup> + OH<sup>-</sup>
- CO<sub>2</sub> + H<sub>2</sub>O = H<sup>+</sup> + HCO<sub>3</sub><sup>-</sup>
- HCO<sub>3</sub><sup>-</sup> = H<sup>+</sup> + CO<sub>3</sub><sup>2-</sup>

which includes 4 reactions and 7 substances?

Comment: I take it $\ln\mathbf{Y}$ is $\ln$ applied to each entry of the vector $\mathbf{Y}$?

Comment: Yes. Are there any simple notations for $(\ln y_1, \ln y_2, ..., \ln y_n)^T$?

Comment: It seems your second equation determines $Y$, so if $N$ has a left inverse we have $\ln Y =N^{-1} \ln K$. With $Y$ known the first equation determines $X$ similarly

Comment: No. The second equation actually includes *m* equations and *n* variables, and generally *n* > *m*.

Answer (score 2):

This problem can be handled with nonlinear programming, through a minimization process.

Follows a self explanatory MATHEMATICA script showing the procedure. You can try it with more complicated arrangements.

```
c = {0, 0, 0.1, 0};
n = {{1, 1, 0, 0}, {0, 1, -1, 1}};
k = {10^-14, 1.77 10^-5};
X = {x1, x2};
Y = {y1, y2, y3, y4};
dif1 = Transpose[n].X - c - Y;
dif2 = n.Log[Y] - Log[k];
obj = Norm[dif1] + Norm[dif2];
vars = Join[X, Y];
restrs = Table[2/10 > vars[[i]] > 10^-14, {i, 1, Length[vars]}];
sol = NMinimize[{obj, restrs}, vars, Method -> "DifferentialEvolution"]
obj /.sol[[2]]
```

It gives a solution better than yours.

Comment: In my second example NH4HCO3/(NH4)2CO3, I don't know how many solutions there are, and I don't know if MATHIMATICA can find all solutions.

Comment: Post your values to verify.

Comment: What's the result? I'm not familiar with Mathematica and I use SciPy's fsolve and encountered some problems: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68302523

Comment: I ran your codes in Mathematica Cloud and got the result `{0.167346,{x1=1.E-14,x2=5.21993E-8,y1=6.92626E-9,,y2=1.44213E-6,y3=0.00711273,y4=0.0846503}}`, which is not correct. The accurate result is `X= [7.56662656e-12 1.32159290e-03] Y= [7.56662656e-12 1.32159291e-03 9.86784071e-02 1.32159290e-03]`.

Comment: If you compute the values for `dif1`and `dif2`with the values which allegedly is the "answer", the residuals are $\{-7.56663, -1.32127, -0.2, 0., 34.5395, 6.90851\}$ and the MATHEMATICA script furnishes the residuals $\{-6.92625*10^-9, -1.38993*10^-6, -0.107113, -0.0846502, -0.00114382, -0.0308008\}$ so the solutions given by the script are much better than the so called "answer". Regards.

Answer (score 0):

Inspired by Cesareo, I tried SciPy's [basinhopping](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.basinhopping.html) and some tips:

1. I use "Nelder-Mead" as minimization method, although very slow, because the function may be non-differentiable. I haven't tried "Powell"; "CG" sometimes doesn't work and BFGSs don't work at all.
2. Set large and gradient "bounds" to avoid negative logarithm, and this also help basinhopping .
3. Set very large iterate count (for both basinhopping and minimize) if system is very complicated, such as [McIlvaine buffer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/McIlvaine_buffer).

Here is my code with SciPy:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import basinhopping

'''
# H2O <-> H+ + OH-
# NH3 + H2O <-> NH4+ + OH-
# [H+, OH-, NH3, NH4+]
# 0.1M NH3
C = np.array([0, 0, 0.1, 0])
N = np.array([
    [1, 1, 0, 0],
    [0, 1, -1, 1]
])
K = np.array([1e-14, 1.77e-5])
X0 = np.array([0, 0])
'''

# H2O <-> H+ + OH-
# CO2 + H2O <-> H+ + HCO3-
# HCO3- <-> H+ + CO32-
# [H+, OH-, CO2, HCO3-, CO32-]
# 0.001M CO2 + 0.01M HCO3-
C = np.array([0, 0, 0.001, 0.01, 0])
N = np.array([
    [1, 1, 0, 0, 0],
    [1, 0, -1, 1, 0],
    [1, 0, 0, -1, 1],
])
K = np.array([1e-14, 4.3e-7, 4.8e-11])
X0 = np.array([0, 0, 0])

def concentr(X):
    return np.matmul(N.transpose(), X) + C

def chem_eq(X):
    C1 = concentr(X)
    bounds = 0
    for c1 in C1:
        if c1 <= 0:
            bounds += (1 - c1)*1e+14
    if bounds > 0:
        return bounds
    return np.linalg.norm(np.matmul(N, np.log(C1)) - np.log(K))

def main():
    print('Inequilibrium:', chem_eq(X0))
    print('Concentrations:', concentr(X0))
    # `niter` should be so large for H3PO4
    result = basinhopping(chem_eq, X0, niter = 1000, \
            minimizer_kwargs = {'method': 'Nelder-Mead', 'options': {'xatol': 1e-14, 'maxiter': 1000}})
    print(result)
    X = result.x
    print('Inequilibrium:', chem_eq(X))
    print('Concentrations:', concentr(X))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Result for 0.1M NH3:

```
[H+] = 7.56662656e-12 (pH = 11.12)
[OH-] = 1.32159291e-03
[NH3] = 9.86784071e-02
[NH4+] = 1.32159290e-03
```

Result for 0.1M NH4HCO3:

```
[H+] = 4.35771835e-08 (pH = 7.36)
[OH-] = 2.29477887e-07
[CO2] = 1.01117642e-03
[HCO3-] = 9.97783306e-03
[CO32-] = 1.09905218e-05
```

btw there is an algorithm called HALTAFALL for equilibrium calculations, which may be much more effective than basinhopping. I found a Java implementation in [this project](https://github.com/ignasi-p/eq-diagr/)